# URLs and justification

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, hyphenation, urls

I am having difficulties in keeping long URLs inside the correct margins in LyX. I can understand why there are difficulties in hyphenating URLs at a point that will ensure the average reader will understand that it's an inserted hyphen and not part of the URL, but is it not possible to ensure that additional spaces are placed in the line (to justify it) so that the URL all appears on one line, or that it breaks at a '/' or similar?

Or is there a more appropriate solution to this problem - here is one example of a problematic line:

```
\footnote{This is based on data for desktop performance found at \texttt{http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/\textasciitilde hpm/book97/ch3/processor.list.txt} - accessed 25 May 2013 - and data we collected on real time device performance.}
```

Comment: try `\usepackage{url}`, and call the url as `\url{xxx}`.  this will allow the url to break in reasonable places and won't add any hyphens.

Comment: In `LyX` go to Insert > URL